# What's the point of COVID-19 testing (for an individual)?

Tags: virus, test-results

I feel I am missing something.  If one has COVID-like symptoms, they should self-quarantine, seeking medical care if the symptoms get to a certain point.  If one has no symptoms, but came into contact with someone who either has symptoms or a positive COVID-19 test, then the same holds true.  So, from a personal perspective, why get tested at all?

Tests are not perfect, and getting a test one day doesn't protect one from being unknowingly exposed the *following* day.

Comment: What research did you do?

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require some degree of prior research when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have to remember that coronavirus is just something added to all the different diseases that existed 6 months ago.

There are tons of bacteria, virus, fungi whose infection could resemble COVID-19 sindrome (i remind you that symptoms can vary and the same symptom can present differently in different patients) that can be treated with simple antibiotics therefore avoiding strict quarantine for that person (and all the related family)

tests are not perfect you are right they are only truthful 90%,95%,99% of times therfore giving a pretty precise estimation of whats happening in the population and all related statistics (on which all the prevention is based, the government decisions ecc...)

Obviously the test is just a "screenshot" of what's happening in a certain person in a specific time and the optimal situation would be take the test every day for every person butsince that is not feasable 1 test every few weeks (or at least one) is good enough still leaving test kits available for people that need a more precise evaluation of the sistuation (people infected, in hospitals, in retirement homes...)

p.s. the so called "personal perspective" in a pandemic is not worth considering since a lot of the decisions taken from my personal perspective do not make any sense but are extremely important from the community perspective (example: "why on hell shouldn't I go outside if there is nobody out there to get the virus from?" makes sense for me as a single but it's deleterious from the society perspective)

Comment: Although your antibiotics concept is interesting (cure the "something else"), it still sounds like there's little reason for such testing *for the individual*.  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Welcome to Medical Sciences! We work differently than most SE sites in that we have a strict policy that all answers should be [backed up with reliable references](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-require-references-to-back-up-all-answers) so that the answer can be independently verified regardless of the reader's background. *See [this list of reliable sources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. If you still have trouble with this, feel free to visit the [help] or [meta]. Unreferenced claims can lead to answers being deleted.